# How to remove duplicates from a chained queryset?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-templates, django-views

I have 3 queries that I have chained together like so in a view:

```
filter1 = Game.objects.filter(genres__name=str('2D'))
filter2 = Game.objects.filter(genres__name=str('Action'))
filter3 = Game.objects.filter(genres__name=str('Sports'))

return chain(filter1, filter2, filter3)
```

I want all games that are genre 2D, Action and Sports but not games that are all 3 at once, just every game that matches each genre (i.e. not a 2D action sports game), but when I use this queryset in a loop in my template, I receive duplicate games if they are both 2D and Action, for example.

I have tried using `distinct()` on the chained queryset, however I get a warning saying `Unresolved attribute reference 'distinct' for class 'chain'`.

Is there some sort of thing I can do on the template which keeps track of which games have already been looped through and build a list of them, so that if the same game comes up after the first queryset has been cycled through, it will miss the duplicate game out?

For example:

```
for game in queryset:
    if game.id is in game_id_list:
        Dont display
    else:
        Display and add to game_id_list
```

Comment: A more efficient query is probably `Game.objects.filter(genres__name__in=['2D', 'Action', 'Sports'])`.

Comment: I added `.distinct()` to the end of that and it does what I was after. Thank you!